# Column not found: 1054 Champ 'feedbacks.student_id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a belongsTo relationship between Feedback and Student.

In my table `Students` I have 3 fields (id, name, firstname).

In my `Feedbacks` I have 3 fields (id, instruction, fk_student).

My sort with alphabetical order is incorrect. I have as message:

`Column not found: 1054 Champ 'feedbacks.student_id`

```
public function index(Request $req) 
    {

    if ($req->search == "") {
        $feedbacks = Feedback::join('students', 'feedbacks.student_id', '=', 'students.id')->orderBy('students.name', 'asc')->select('feedbacks.*')->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));

    } else {

        $validated = $req->validate([
            'search' => 'alpha', 
        ]);

        $feedbacks = Feedback::join('students', 'feedbacks.student_id', '=', 'students.id')->where('students.name','like', '%' . $req->search . '%')->orderBy('students.name', 'asc')->select('feedbacks.*')->paginate(5);

        return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
        }

    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you said here

> In my Feedbacks I have 3 fields (id, instruction, fk_student).

Therefore it should be like this

```
public function index(Request $req) 
{

if ($req->search == "") {
    $feedbacks = Feedback::join('students', 'feedbacks.fk_student', '=', 'students.id')->orderBy('students.name', 'asc')->select('feedbacks.*')->paginate(5);
    return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));

} else {

    $validated = $req->validate([
        'search' => 'alpha', 
    ]);

    $feedbacks = Feedback::join('students', 'feedbacks.fk_student', '=', 'students.id')->where('students.name','like', '%' . $req->search . '%')->orderBy('students.name', 'asc')->select('feedbacks.*')->paginate(5);

    return view('admin.feedbacks.index', compact('feedbacks'));
    }

}
```

You said in feedbacks its `fk_student` then its not `student_id`.

Hope it helps